# How to setup virtual host in Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to setup virtual host for one of my webapp in Tomcat 8 which is running on port 8080.

http://localhost:8080/cicd-demo works fine !

www.cicd-demo.com does NOT WORK !!!!

## Error Log:

```
The server at www.cicd-demo.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.
```

## server.xml configuration

```
  <Host name="cicd-demo.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.cicd-demo.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="cicd_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="" docBase="C:/apache-tomcat/webapps/cicd-demo" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
  </Host>
```

Do I have to configure the port 8080 somewhere? What am I missing?

Comment: How have you mapped your domain name to the ip of your tomcat.

Comment: No, not sure how to do that.

Comment: You woud have done some configuration so that when i hit www.cicd-demo.com, it should point to your tomcat instance.

Comment: Has this something to do with modifying the hosts.etc file in Windows ?

Comment: Does this domain www.cicd-demo.com belong to you.

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to avoid typing http://localhost:8080/cicd-demo again and again !

Comment: I just added following entry in hosts.etc file and it opened my WAMP server console `192.168.231.49 www.cicd-demo.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82860/discussion-between-johnson-abraham-and-user2325154).

Comment: With this configuration you will be able to access your tomcat with www.cicd-demo.com:8080/